# Por que sobrescrever os elementos de um vetor gasta mesmo tempo que da primeira vez?

Tags: c++

Meu objetivo com esse teste seria comparar o desempenho de velocidade entre essas duas funções:

```
static inline void VectAssign1(int *const g , const int x , int n )
{
    // g[ i ] = x for each i = 0 .. n - 1

    for( int *tg = g + n ; tg > g ; )
        *(--tg) = x;
}

static inline void VectAssign2(int *g , const int x , int n )
{
    // g[ i ] = x for each i = 0 .. n - 1

    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        g[i] = x;
}
```

para isso montei o seguinte:

```
    int main() {

    clock_t t;
    const int n = 100000000;

    int* v = new int[n];
    int* w = new int[n];

    t = clock();
    VectAssign1(v,10,n);
    t = clock() - t;

    cout << ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    //print(v,n);

    t = clock();
    VectAssign2(v,10,n);
    t = clock() - t;

    cout << ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    //print(w,n);

    return 0;
}
```

Enviei o mesmo vetor v para as duas funções, sendo que na segunda vez eu sobrescrevo os valores de v novamente, e vi que o tempo e muito superior na primeira chamada:

- 1)0.387355
- 2)0.218332

Para deixar mais claro enviei vetores diferentes:

```
    clock_t t;
    const int n = 100000000;

    int* v = new int[n];
    int* w = new int[n];

    t = clock();
    VectAssign1(v,10,n);
    t = clock() - t;

    cout << ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    //print(v,n);

    t = clock();
    VectAssign2(w,10,n);
    t = clock() - t;

    cout << ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    //print(w,n);

    return 0;
```

obtive as saídas:

- 1)0.435841
- 2)0.436091

---

1. Porque chamando as duas funções com o mesmo vetor, o tempo de sobreescrer pela segunda vez é menor?
2. Como podemos perceber, com vetores diferentes para cada vetor, e também inicializando os vetores pela primeira vez, o desempenho das duas funções são idênticas. Se alguem pode responder, existe uma preferencia pela primeira ou segunda maneira de inicializar os elementos de um vetor?

Comment: Nem fiz uma análise do código, mas o mais provável é o cache.

Comment: isso mesmo, cache do processador, E, clock, quando você inicia um processo em loop, seu processador vai demorar um pouco pra "perceber" que precisa aumentar a frequência, gradativamente, você vai ver este impacto no aumento gradativo do uso de CPU